# Using lightning:progressIndicator

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

Has anyone been able to get the new components in the Winter '18 release to work? I updated my component to the latest API and could not get it to work.

Also, is there any documentation giving examples of how the new tags can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a sample of code:

```
<lightning:progressIndicator type="path" currentStep="step2">
    <lightning:progressStep label="Step One" value="step1"/>
    <lightning:progressStep label="Step Two" value="step2"/>
    <lightning:progressStep label="Step Three" value="step3"/>
</lightning:progressIndicator>
```

You can specify two types:

- base: basic progress bar with steps
- path: the path with steps used for example on the opportunities

Use the `currentStep` attribute to specify the current step value.

The documentation is available here:

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_progressIndicator.htm

**Note**

Don't forget to change the API version of your Lightning component to `41` if you created the component before the Winter18 release.